# What is msg.value?

Tags: solidity

Can somebody explain what is the magic `msg.value`? I came across this code:
https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/solidity/

```
/// @return The balance of the user after the deposit is made
function deposit() public payable returns (uint) {
    // Use 'require' to test user inputs, 'assert' for internal invariants
    // Here we are making sure that there isn't an overflow issue
    require((balances[msg.sender] + msg.value) >= balances[msg.sender]);

    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    // no "this." or "self." required with state variable
    // all values set to data type's initial value by default

    LogDepositMade(msg.sender, msg.value); // fire event

    return balances[msg.sender];
}
```

I do not see where the msg.value coming from, when a user deposit eth, does he or she needs to pass in the amount from the deposit function?
Thanks and sorry for newbie question.

Edit:

From the following contract, I do not see anywhere passing in msg.value, so how this msg.value has been assigned? by the way you link of cryptozombie is very interesting, thanks.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract ClientReceipt {

    event Deposit(
        address indexed _from,
        bytes32 indexed _id,
        uint _value
    );

    function deposit(bytes32 _id) public payable {
        // Events are emitted using `emit`, followed by
        // the name of the event and the arguments
        // (if any) in parentheses. Any such invocation
        // (even deeply nested) can be detected from
        // the JavaScript API by filtering for `Deposit`.
        emit Deposit(msg.sender, _id, msg.value);
    }
}
```

http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#function-modifiers

Answer (score 31):

`msg.value` is a member of the msg (message) object when sending (state transitioning) transactions on the Ethereum network.

`msg.value` contains the amount of wei (ether / 1e18) sent in the transaction.

```markdown
msg.data (bytes): complete calldata
msg.gas (uint): remaining gas - deprecated in version 0.4.21 and to be replaced by gasleft()
msg.sender (address): sender of the message (current call)
msg.sig (bytes4): first four bytes of the calldata (i.e. function identifier)
msg.value (uint): number of wei sent with the message
```

Comment: Nico, isn't your definition of wei backward? A wei is ether * 1^e-18, right?  Reading your response it sounds like a wei is 10^18 larger than an ether, not 10^18 smaller....

Comment: 1 ether is 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 wei
so to go from ether to wei we need to add 18 zero's
To go from wei to ether we need to move the decimal point forward 18 places. I could be wrong in my notation , i'm not a mathematician :)

Comment: Right.  It's the notation I was carping about, because you described 1 wei as being 10**18 ether, not the other wei around.  Sorry, couldn't resist.  ... I think most people would understand it was backward, but newbies could get confused.

Comment: Just change your "*" to a "/" and it'll be fine.

Comment: I guess I need to understand the msg(message) object more, when you send transaction, you are executing a transfer or send function of a contract, how does the message object come into the picture? when a contract is defined, I never see how msg object is defined in the contract or initialized or assigned anywhere, just see msg.sender or msg.value show up or used in a contract. any pointer to read more about? Thanks

Comment: I could type alot but I think this might be better: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper#messages-and-transactions

Comment: Simply put the msg object is the pack of data you are sending in transactions. 

When simply sending ether from one address to another msg.data will be empty.

When calling upon a contract without having to send ether with the call msg.value will be 0 and msg.data will contain the calldata.

Answer (score 6):

`msg.value` is automatically set to the amount of ether sent with that `payable` function.

More info here: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=msg.value#block-and-transaction-properties

Comment: Do you mean it is the gas fee? the link says: msg.value (uint): number of wei sent with the message, that depends on the message refers to which function call, some functions are not payable, so no msg.value associated, right? also how do I set msg.value or how to send it?

Comment: @idoor `msg.value`: number of wei sent with the message. Wei is just the smallest uint of ether. It's just referencing how much was actually sent with the message. Not the gas fee.

Comment: Also what happens if the contract has no payable function? and no functions which send in msg.value?

Comment: @idoor Any function called that is *not* payable but a `msg.value` is sent, will be reverted and fail. `msg.value` goes back to the user minus the gas used.

Comment: Thanks very much ReyHaynes, what is the msg.value when a contract is just deployed and nobody has never called any functions yet except the owner deploys it? for instance the contract is deployed with a supply of 100000. and also how do you send msg.value? do I need to write a function in the contract to send msg.value?

Comment: @idoor `msg.value` is the value set when a user calls the function and sends a value at the same time. If you deploy a contract with a payable constructor, `msg.value` will be the value sent with the deployed contract.

Comment: @idoor Since you seem new to contract development, I suggest you go through this easy tutorial the help you understand further: https://cryptozombies.io

Answer (score 4):

You can define value parameter while seding the transaction .Below example can give better explanation

```
   ContractInterface.methods
      .contractmethod(parameter)
       .send({
         from: accounts[0],
         value : "amount in ether or wei"
    });
```

Above value will be available as msg.value

Answer (score 0):

It is a parameter users send along when they call a function in smart contract. It is the amount of wei you send to the smart contract. 
If you use remix you will see there is a input labeled "value" to put this parameter.

If you call the function from javascript you can put this parameter as Arjun recommended above. 
ContractInterface.methods
      .contractmethod(parameter)
       .send({
         from: accounts[0],
         value : "amount in ether or wei"
    });

You said that you are a newbie, so the article might be quite difficult to understand. I recommend that you should read easier articles than that one. You can start with https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.25/solidity-in-depth.html or other tutorials.  [image]